# My OpenGL Version doesn't support Buffer Binding

Tags: opengl, hardware, drivers

Why is this? I'd like to know because in a LOT of articles and various tutorials I see on the Internet it's hard NOT to see something which doesn't deal with buffer binding. The only bind function I have is `glBindTexture`. Does this mean my drivers are significantly outdated?

**Edit**

Sorry for lack of information. My OpenGL version 3.1 from an Intel integrated GPU. Also, the reason why I thought that I lacked functions such as `glBindBuffer` is mainly because it wouldn't show up in Qt as a function I could use in my auto-completion.

Comment: -1: For lack of information. What version of OpenGL are you initializing? When you say that it "doesn't support" it, do you mean that you get link errors when you try to use `glBindBuffer`, or that the function pointer doesn't load? What OpenGL loading library are you using? What platform are you on?

Comment: Please read the [Getting Started page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started) on the OpenGL Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only bind function I have is `glBindTexture`

Most likely you're fooled by the way OpenGL implementations export their functionality. opengl32.dll on Windows will and libGL.so most likely will give you only OpenGL-1.1 functionality (Windows Vista and / actually do give you OpenGL-1.4 and most Linux/BSD drivers will give you OpenGL-2.1). Anything beyond (and buffer objects go beyond) must be loaded through the so called *extension system*.

Most easy and reliable way to do this:

1. Go to http://glew.sf.net get the version matching your development environment
2. Install GLEW in development environment
3. Replace all occurences of `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <GL/glew.h>`
4. Call `glewInit()` in your code after a OpenGL context has been made current.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you.